# Can I put the exception handler of the microservices in an independent service?

Tags: spring-boot, microservices

I have a microservices architecture using spring boot with a couple of services and one base service that the services use as jar.
Can I put the exception handler for the whole project in the base service or should each service have its own exception handler ? If yes, does the base service need to be a spring boot application and should it be running ?

Comment: Please add more information, such as the hierarchy of the app and code snippets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can include the exception handler inside your base service and it doesn't need to be a springboot application, all you have to do is create a @Configuration class inside your other services and load the class of the base service where you have defined your exception handler.

something line this:

```
@Configuration
@Import({ ExceptionHandler.class })
```